# Background Image of Button not showing in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have program in which I have lots of buttons. Each of button has background set as

```
  <Button x:Name="mybutton"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="76,110,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="25" Click="some_click">
                <Button.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Resource/button_picture.png"/>
                </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

Image is showing as background in **.xaml** when program not running  but when i run application image is not there as background of button. How do i debug this background in button ?  Is there any goofy error that is there?

Comment: Any news on the result of this question?

Comment: it was my stupid mistake in code itself found it

Comment: Can you tell me more as I am having the exact same issue now....

Comment: I was clearing the background myself in loading event of window, so no matter what i put in xaml,  it will get clear in C#

Answer (score 6):

Let's make sure we have the following properties set right in your scenario

1) Build Action -> Resource

2) Copy to Output Directory -> Do not copy

3) Instead of using the relative path for image source, try using a full path to the image like this (I say this because I don't know where the image resource is located in your project, using relative path is perfectly normal in WPF)

```
<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/AssemblyNameContainingImageResource;component/Resource/button_picture.png" />
```

Comment: The third suggestion helped me!!

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the code like this

```
<Button x:Name="mybutton"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="76,110,0,0"    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="25" Click="some_click">
    <Image Source="Resource/button_picture.png"/>
</Button>
```

Comment: this even removes image as button background when application not running and when running application it does not show either

Answer (score 0):

Change the Build Action of button_picture.png to Resource if it is content. Also check the Copy to output directory property value

Comment: I am not able to reproduce it. Can you provide more code which may be related to this button?